# elasticsearch not honouring mapping file when two processes are indexing at the same time

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot

We have a Spring Boot Java ETL application that creates an elasticsearch index each time it runs and then flips an alias to point to the index it created.

We create the index through the Java API and specify a mapping file and disable dynamic mapping.

```
    prepareCreate.addMapping(index.getType(), loadMappingJson(mapping), JSON);
    prepareCreate.setSettings(Settings.builder().put("index.mapper.dynamic", false));
```

If just one instance of our APP is running this process works.  When a second instance is introduced and indexing is running concurrently the index that gets created does not use the mapping file and uses dynamic mapping based on the first document loaded.

What's happening that's causing the dynamic mapping setting to be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

> index that gets created does not use the mapping file and uses dynamic mapping based on the first document loaded.

This means that you are sending your index request toward a **non-existing** index, therefore ElasticSearch creates the index together with the first document, using the mapping suggested by it.

Most likely, your index creation request get lost or arrives after the first document has been indexed.